# С++ с ассемблерной вставкой

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать ассемблерную вставку на "
разность сумм четных и нечетных элементов массива"

Компилирую в g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

В данный момент столкнулся с ошибкой(приведена внизу кода)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int result;

    asm(
        "xorl %%eax, %%eax\n"  
        "xorl %%ecx, %%ecx\n" 
        "1: \n"
        "movl %[arr], %%esi\n"  
        "movl (%%esi, %%ecx, 4), %%edx\n" 

        "testl %%edx, %%edx\n"  
        "jz 2f\n"

        "testb $1, %%dl\n"
        "jnz even\n"

        "addl %%edx, %%eax\n" 
        "jmp continue\n"

        "even:\n"
        "subl %%edx, %%eax\n" 

        "continue:\n"
        "incl %%ecx\n" 
        "jmp 1b\n"

        "2:\n"

        : "=a" (result)
        : [arr] "r" (arr.data())
        : "%edx", "%ecx", "%esi"
    );

    std::cout << "Результат: " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ -o asm asm.cpp
asm.cpp: Сообщения ассемблера:
asm.cpp:13: Ошибка: неподдерживаемая инструкция «mov»
```